# PIXI.js loader shared resources texture detect typo in name

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, pixi.js

In our game we use typescript, pixi.js, vscode, eslint.

We have a dictionary of image files like this

```
export function getAllImages(): {name: string, extension: string}[] {
    return [
        {name: 'tile_lumber', extension: '.svg'},
        {name: 'tile_brick', extension: '.svg'},
        ....
    ]
}
```

which is loaded like this

```
export function loadImages() {
    for(const img of getAllImages()) {
        PIXI.Loader.shared.add(img.name, getImagePath(img.name + img.extension), { crossOrigin: true })
    }

    PIXI.Loader.shared
        .on('progress', loadProgressHandler)
        .load(assetsFinishedLoading)
}
```

When we call the item we write it like this

```
export function getBannerForPlayer(playerColor: PlayerColors): PIXI.Texture {
    switch(playerColor) {
        case PlayerColors.Bronze: return PIXI.Loader.shared.resources.banner_bronze.texture
        case PlayerColors.Silver: return PIXI.Loader.shared.resources.banner_silver.texture
        case PlayerColors.Gold: return PIXI.Loader.shared.resources.banner_goldf.texture
        ....
    }
}
```

This code does not give an error in the compiler even though there is no texture called `banner_goldf` it should be `banner_gold`. We accidentally pushed this code and it has caused a bug in the game.

Ideally vscode, tsc or something else should be showing error for cases like this. How can we make sure that it shows error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead if having a list of definitions, you can define a static variable for each image like so:

```
export class ImageDefinition {
    name: string
    extension: string
    texture: PIXI.Texture | undefined
}

export class Images {
    static icon_player: ImageDefinition = {name: 'icon_player', extension: '.svg', texture: undefined }
}
```

The images can be loaded with

```
for(const img in Images) {
    const image: ImageDefinition = Images[img]
    PIXI.Loader.shared.add(image.name, getImagePath(image.name + image.extension), { crossOrigin: true })
}
```

After the images have been loaded, you can store the loaded textures in your static variables

```
export function assetsFinishedLoading() {
    for(const img in Images) {
        const image: ImageDefinition = Images[img]
        image.texture = PIXI.Loader.shared.resources[image.name].texture
    }
}
```

You can now reference the textures like:

```
const texture = Images.icon_player.texture
```